# Javascript not loading I think xampp is blocking it

Tags: javascript, xampp

I am running a xampp server on my Windows 10 machine.

My javascript is not working. My directories are fine, as the css works. 
What is happening here? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rhWI.png)

Comment: show your code how you included js.

Comment: JS path could be wrong...

Comment: Thanks for the help and the suggestions, but I think I fixed it enough to take me through the rest of the project. What a long two days, and what a learning experience Gahan, and Muthu Kumaran!

Answer (score 1):

As per the screenshot, it seems like you have not added file extension to the files i.e. `font-awesome.min` should be `font-awesome.min.js` or file path is not correct (status: 404)

Comment: Thank you Nikhil Arora, but I believe I fixed it, enough to get me through to the end of the project, anyway... My problem seems to be in my Javascript somewhere, and since I don't know enough about Javascript yet, I had to find my own solution so I can get on with the class. Again, thanks for reaching out.